# How to pull specific remote branch in VS Code Remote Container

Tags: git, docker, visual-studio-code, containers, docker-for-windows

Is it possible to checkout a specific branch to the container Repo as done by the following command on a "normal" cloned Repo?

```
git clone --branch <branchname> <remote-repo-url>
```

I have one branch, which I started to work on in a container but the vscode extension only allows "Clone Repo":

[image]

If I clone the Repo on another machine, I am facing an issue due to checkout other remote branches.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess it works, if I use the shell command shown below:

```
git clone --branch <branchname> <remote-repo-url>
```

Afterwards I can open the entire folder within vscode. If [Remote-Container Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#:%7E:text=The%20Visual%20Studio%20Code%20Remote,Studio%20Code%27s%20full%20feature%20set.) is installed, enabled the branch is already set up with a devcontainer.json, a pop-up window will allow you to open the current branch in a container.

As mentioned by [@nelsonjchen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/286021/nelsonjchen), it seems , it is only working for Github.

Comment: That's not the same. If you do that, you bind mount a volume from your host to the container. On Windows and Mac, this bridge can be pretty expensive.

Comment: The issue to do that with Clone Volume is tracked at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4296 and it seems it only works for GitHub.